# I want to know if the phrase below is a participial phrase

Tags: participle-phrases

I saw the sentence below in a test passage.

> Longer life spans mean more people, worsening food and housing supply difficulties.

Is "worsening food and housing supply difficulties" a participial phrase here?

And I cannot guess what is a subject of "worsening".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Worsening food* is a noun phrase, with head *food* and participle *worsening* being used adjectivally to modify *food*.

*Housing supply difficulties* is another noun phrase, with three nouns: *housing* (which is a substantivised gerund) modifies *supply*, and *housing supply* modifies *difficulties*.

There is no participal phrase as I understand the term.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can see the structure.

Answer (score 1):

No. This sentence describes three things that longer life spans lead to: more people, worsening food, and housing supply difficulties. This is one of those situations where an [Oxford comma](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/what-is-the-oxford-comma) might have made the meaning more clear:

> Longer life spans mean more people, worsening food **,** and housing supply difficulties.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post.